# QT SQlite login application

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am creating an app that requires log in from user.

My problem is that even if the user enters any username or password the code gets executed as if they logged in correctly.

```
QString email, password;

email = ui->loginEmailbox->text();
password = ui->loginPassbox->text();

QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("SELECT email FROM userRecords WHERE email = (:email)");
qry.bindValue(":email", email);
qry.prepare("SELECT password FROM userRecords WHERE password = (:password)");
qry.bindValue(":password", password);

if(qry.exec()){
    if(qry.next()){
        userMenu usermenu;
        usermenu.setModal(true);
        usermenu.exec();
    }
}else
    ui->loginStatusL->setText("Log-in failed, username or password incorrect!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are preparing 2 queries and executing one. Now if any password matches this will log in.

```
qry.prepare("SELECT DISTINCT email FROM userRecords WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");
qry.bindValue(":email", email);
qry.bindValue(":password", password);
```

This should work but it's not the best / safest way to check credentials.